# Unity Rigidbody has velocity but not moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game in Unity where cubes are repeatedly moved past the camera. I move the cube using a script where I set its Rigidbody's velocity each update. Once it moves out of view my script instantiates a new cube on the other side which begins the process again.
Recently I've found that it works fine for a random amount of cubes before, seemingly randomly, a cube is instantiated that does not move. Using the inspector I can see that this object has velocity. If I move it even a small amount using the editor it starts to move as normal.
Has anyone seen something like this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain the problem was related to the fact I was trying to directly modify the velocity( The physics engine decided the object was at rest and stopped it moving. ). By setting the object to be kinematic and modifying its position in my code I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are changing the velocity of your gameObject when it goes through a specific coordinate (in an if statement for example), unity is not very accurate sometimes with coordinates so it may be happening that the condition is never met. Change that condition and add a margin range to solve this error.

Comment: I change the velocity every update loop( As it speeds up as time goes by ), So I wouldn't say this is the problem.